# Trouble with foreach and post data

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I have a form on a website and it's supposed to be emailed to me.

```
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email 
        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }
```

This works just fine, but I ran into a problem with checkboxes, these should result in an array right? So I tried this:

```
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email 
        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            if (is_array($fields[$key]))
            {
                $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: ";
                foreach ($fields[$key] as $inKey => $inValue)
                {
                    $emailText .= "$inValue";
                    $emailText .= ",";
                }
                $emailText .= "\n";
            }
            else
            {
                $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

But it seems the is_array if is never triggered... not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Am I wrong to assume that checkboxes return an array? Because if I run it as the first version it only gives me the last checked box as value.

Comment: Before your loop, run `print_r($_POST)` to visually see what's in there

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the answer.

To ensure that the $_POST data for checkboxes are an array I needed to append the name of the field with [].

And I wasn't checking the right thing to see if it was an array or not.

```
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email 
    if (isset($fields[$key])) {
        if (is_array($value))
        {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: ";
            foreach ($value as $inKey => $inValue)
            {
                $emailText .= "$inValue";
                $emailText .= ",";
            }
            $emailText .= "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }
```